# OpenMP nested parallelization

Tags: c++, openmp

I am using a library that is already parallelized with OpenMP. The issue is that 2-4 cores seem enough for the processing it is doing. Using more than 4 cores makes little difference.

My code is like this:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<4; ++i)
    Call_To_Library (i, ...);
```

Since 4 cores seem enough for the library (i.e, 4 cores should be used in `Call_To_Library`), and I am working with a 16 cores machine, I intend to also parallelize my for loop. Note that this `for` consists at most of 3-4 iterations.

What would be the best approach to parallelize this outer for? Can I also use OpenMP? Is it a best practice to use nested parallelizations? The library I am calling already uses OpenMP and I cannot modify its code (and it wouldn't be straightforward anyway).

PS. Even if the outer loop consists only of 4 iterations, it is worth parallelizing. Each call to the library takes 4-5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no dependency between iterations of this loop you can do:

```
 #pragma omp for schedule(static)
 for (size_t i=0; i<4; ++i)
    Call_To_Library (i, ...);
```

If, as you said, every invocation of Call_To_Library takes such a big amount of time the overhead of having nested OpenMP operators will probably be negligible.

Moreover you say that you have no control over the number of openmp threads created in Call_To_Library. This solution will multiply the number of openmp threads by 4 and most likely you will see a 4x speedup. Probably the inner Call_To_Library was parallelized in such a way that no more than a few openmp threads could be executed at the same time. With the external parallel for you increase that number 4 times.

The problem with nested parallelism **could** be that you have an explosion of the number of threads created at the same time and therefore you could see less than ideal speedup because of the overhead related to creation/closing of openmp threads.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I also need to call `openmp_set_nested()`. How can I make sure the outer for is creating only 4 threads and the call to the library other 4 threads? I.e., 4x4=16 threads.

Comment: You can control the number of openmp worker threads with the env variable OMP_NUM_THREADS.

Comment: OK, I think I can use OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable to control the worker threads of the library. For the outer loop I can use a num_threads clause (maybe in the future I want a 8x2 threads scheme).

Comment: I added to my answer. Moreover you can use `omp_get_num_threads()` within the parallel for region to check how many threads are actually running.

Comment: I don't undestand second scenario. Even if the library is badly parallelized, it will still use only 4 cores. Even in this scenario I should see a 4x speedup. Note that each call to the library is processing an independent chunk of data.

Comment: My explanation wasn't very clear and I rephrased that second part :)

Comment: OK, I understand now. Since I am multiplying the number of openmp threads by 4 and I don't think the library is using nested threads, I guess I won't see such an explosion. Thanks